# Actually PIN a message to top or bottom of Slack channel

Tags: slack-api

As our company uses Slack for many things, it seemed like it might be a great place to have a company wide message always appear to users.  It seems odd to me, that Slack does not seem to support such a thing anywhere.  I'd welcome any input on how I can use the API to update a message that always appears at the top (or bottom) of the Slack application for our users.

I've tried using the chat.postMessage, followed by pins.add.  But all this does is add a message to a list of other pins.  It doesn't actually cause the message to appear at the top or bottom of a given channel.  It eventually gets lost in the stream, unless someone specifically clicks the pins button.

I've also tried to figure out a way to do a chat.update, to modify the timestamp of a post so it would appear at the bottom of the list on some set interval.  But it doesn't appear that you can modify the timestamp of a post.

I'm contemplating just occasionally posting new status updates.  But that feels much more intrusive as it will show up as a new message, as opposed to just being a message at the top/bottom of the feed.

Any ideas/options that might work as I'm describing?